# Powershell - MultiLine Regex splitting

Tags: regex, powershell

What I'm trying to do is take a sql script block and strip out the 'GO' statements.

I think I have a proper regex created; `(?smi)(.*?)^GO$`; as it looks to be working here:  https://regex101.com/r/Mg58zl/1

Below is what I currently have for a powershell script; but I'm not getting the results I'm expecting.  I seem to be getting one big match on the entire input; rather than 2 matches; each representing a statement within the GO delimiters.  Any ideas on what I have wrong here?

```
#$fileContent = [io.file]::ReadAllText("C:\temp\script.sql")
$fileContent = @"
GO
    IF NOT EXISTS  (select 1 
                from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable' 
                and COLUMN_NAME = 'NewColumn')   
        BEGIN
            ALTER TABLE MyTable 
            ADD NewColumn bit not null DEFAULT(0)
        END
go
    IF NOT EXISTS  (select 1 
                from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'AnotherTable' 
                and COLUMN_NAME = 'AnotherNewColumn')   
        BEGIN
            ALTER TABLE AnotherTable 
            ADD AnotherNewColumn bit not null DEFAULT(0)
        END
GO
"@
$matchInfo = $fileContent | Select-String '(?smi)(^.*?)^GO$' -AllMatches
```

Comment: You need `(?smi)(.*?)^GO\r?$` at least, to account for CRLF endings.

Comment: Try ``[regex]::Matches($fileContent, '(?smi)(.*?)^GO\r?$') | % { "MATCH: $($_.Groups[1].value)`n--END OF MATCH---" }``. What matches do you expect?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew; post that as an answer; seems to be fixing my issue

Comment: Why the `Select-String` detour? `$fileContent -replace '(?sm)^GO$'` should give you what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the `(?m)GO$` will match `GO` only at the end of the string or a line that has LF only ending. You need to add `\r?` before `$` to match both LF and CRLF endings

You may get and print the captured substrings (that reside in Group 1) with

```
[regex]::Matches($fileContent, '(?smi)(.*?)^GO\r?$') | % { "MATCH: $($_.Groups[1].value)`n--END OF MATCH---" }
```

Note the `$_.Groups[1].value` that accesses Group 1 memory buffer. Matches are access using `$_.value`. You may do whatever you need with the results instead of printing.

Answer (score 0):

Can tou try this :

```
$a = [regex]::Matches($fileContent,  '(?smi)(^GO.*?END)')
```

`$a[0].Captures[0].value` gives :

```
GO
    IF NOT EXISTS  (select 1 
                from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable' 
                and COLUMN_NAME = 'NewColumn')   
        BEGIN
            ALTER TABLE MyTable 
            ADD NewColumn bit not null DEFAULT(0)
        END
```

`$a[1].Captures[0].value` gives :

```
go
    IF NOT EXISTS  (select 1 
                from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'AnotherTable' 
                and COLUMN_NAME = 'AnotherNewColumn')   
        BEGIN
            ALTER TABLE AnotherTable 
            ADD AnotherNewColumn bit not null DEFAULT(0)
        END
```